# Prove que $E$ idempotent is self-adjoint if and only if $EE^*=E^*E$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and let $E$ be a idempotent linear operator om $V$, i.e. $E^2 = E$. Prove que $E$ is self-adjoint if and only if $EE^*=E^*E$.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670098/tt-tt-and-t2-t-prove-t-is-self-adjoint-t-t?lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Write $V=U\oplus W$ where $E|_U$ is the identity and $E|_W$ is the zero map. Then compare $\langle u+w,E(u'+w')\rangle$ with $\langle E^*(u+w),u'+w'\rangle$. What can you conclude about $E^*u$? $E^*w$?