# Are there any operators which are idempotent but not self adjoint? And how we prove them idempotent but not self adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis

How can we prove that an operator which is idempotent but not self adjoint exists?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319197/normal-idempotent-operator-implies-self-adjointness) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683743/prove-que-e-idempotent-is-self-adjoint-if-and-only-if-ee-ee) tell you exactly where you should look for such operators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normal, idempotent operator implies self-adjointness.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319197/normal-idempotent-operator-implies-self-adjointness)

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:** An idempotent operator $T:H \to H$, where $H$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space, is self adjoinf if and only if $TT^* =  T^*T$.

**A proof outline:** Let $T$ be an idempotent operator, that is $T^2 = T$. Then $T$ has a basis of eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalues of $0$ and $1$, as any vector $x$ can be written as: $$x = Tx + (I-T)x.$$
Then $T$ is self-adjoint if and only if the eigenspaces yielded above are mutually orthogonal, which translates to:

\begin{align*}
\langle Tx,(I-T)y\rangle=0,\; \forall x,y &\iff \langle x,T^*(I-T)y\rangle = 0, \; \forall x,y \\
      &\iff T^*(I-T)y=0,\; \forall y \\
      &\iff T^*(I-T) = 0 \\
      &\iff T^* = T^*T
\end{align*}
where the last condition holds if and only if $T^*=T^*T = (T^*T)^*=TT^*$.

**Corollary:** [Any contraction idempotent mapping describes a self-adjoint operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047952/is-a-contraction-idempotent-operator-self-adjoint).

**Edit:** The linked questions by Arthur also contribute to the answer of your question precisely.