# How to show such group of $P(X) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{g\in G} gXg^T$ are self-adjoint?

Tags: matrices, adjoint-operators

1. Let $G$ be a group of "diagonal sign matrices $(g)$", i.e. a **diagonal matrix** with **diagonal entries in $\{-1,1\}$**.  So $G$ is of cardinality $2^n$.  For example:   $$g = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0 \\0 & -1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
2. Define $$P(X) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{g\in G} gXg^T$$  with $X\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$

> My question: How to show $P$ is self-adjont?

So, obviously we have to show $P^T=P$:

$$P^T = \big(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{g\in G} gXg^T\big)^T = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{g\in G} \big(gXg^T\big)^T=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{g\in G} gX^Tg^T$$

How to go a step further?

---

http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4914 (p.1326)

[image]

Comment: What exactly is $X$ here? I.e., what space is $P$ operating on?

Comment: @Mark I correct my article. $P$ just operate on $X$ by multiplication of $g$ and summation over all elements in $G$ and average (divided by $2^n$). $X\in R^{n\times n}$, so $X$ is arbitrary square real matrix with dimension $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose some $h\in G$ and fix $X$.  Then
\begin{equation}
hP(X)h^T = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{g\in G} hgXg^Th^T = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{g\in G} (hg)X(hg)^T = P(X).
\end{equation}
So we have
\begin{equation}
P(P(X)) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{g\in G} gP(X)g^T = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{g\in G} P(X) = P(X),
\end{equation}
meaning that $P$ is idempotent.  Some similar trickery will show that $PP^T = P^T$ and that $P^T P=P^T$.  The fact that $PP^T = P^TP$ means that $P$ is a *normal* operator, and you can find arguments (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319197/normal-idempotent-operator-implies-self-adjointness) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670098/tt-tt-and-t2-t-prove-t-is-self-adjoint-t-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)) showing that all normal, idempotent operators are self-adjoint.

Comment: How could you say $P$ is idempotent?  An idempotent matrix $M$ is defined as: $MM = M$. $P(P(X)) = P(X)$ looks like composition rule?

Comment: Idempotence isn't just for matrices: a function $f$ is called idempotent if $f=f\circ f$ (when this composition makes sense).

Comment: @AustinC could you give more details about how you derive $PP^T=P^T$?

Comment: @stewbasic As with $P$, we can show that $hP^T(X)h^T=P^T(X)$ for every $h\in G$ and every $X$.  Then we can compute $P(P^T(X))=P^T(X)$ in the same way that $P(P(X))$ is computed in the second line above.

Comment: @AustinC This requires first describing $P^T(X)$, right? As far as I can see, the easiest way to do so is to show that $\langle P(X),Y\rangle=\langle X,P(Y)\rangle$ so $P^T=P$, but then the question is already answered.

Comment: @stewbasic $P^T(X)$ is given in the original post (though it's written as just $P^T$).

Comment: @AustinC The expression in the original post is for $P(X)^T$, which is not in general the same as $P^T(X)$ (it happens to be in this case, but that is not clear a priori).

Comment: Good catch.  With this in mind, I don't immediately see how to patch up my solution, so I'll delete it shortly.  Thanks for catching my error!

Comment: @AustinC I provide the original article of my problem. $P(X)$ is a function, if fact $P(X)$ is a diagonal matrix whatever $X$ is. In fact you do not need to delete your answer, your answer provides a good way to thinking,

Comment: The answer can't be deleted since it's been accepted, but I still think it's not quite right, as per stewbasic's comment.  It should be noted that the proof in the linked paper doesn't match the snippet given above.